# How run code in dart when we await void method

Tags: flutter, dart

How will be executed `secondMethod` in code, synchronously or asynchronously?

````
void _firstMethod() async {
    await _secondMethod();
}

void _secondMethod() async {
  await _someCalculations();
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#handling-futures):

> Although an async function might perform time-consuming operations, it doesn’t wait for those operations. Instead, the async function executes only until it encounters its first await expression (details). Then it returns a Future object, resuming execution only after the await expression completes.

- `_firstMethod` will be run synchronously all the way up to the first `await` keyword.
- Then, it will encounter the call to `_secondMethod`.
- In the same way, the `_secondMethod` will be called and run synchronously all the way up to the first await, which is the `_someCalculations` function.
- This function will be called asynchronously, and after the required time, it will return its value,
- thus completing the rest of `_secondMethod`,
- which will return to the `_firstMethod`, finally concluding it.

From the same link above, you should think of the async/await as a way to write asynchronous code that looks synchronous. This way you can understand it more easily as a linear flow of information, when needed.

Comment: Does it mean, that void someMethod() async {} is equals Future<void> someMethod() async {}?

Comment: No. There is no such thing as ```void someMethod() async {}```. From [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await) it says that when adding the async keyword you should modify the return value to a Future<type>.